# CSS Checkbox Invalid Error Border Box Around Group of Options

Tags: css, typescript, bootstrap-4

How could I create a bordered red box around checkboxes that weren't selected but were required?
I have it written this way at the moment.

```
    <div class="fb-checkbox-group form-group field-checkbox-group-1500575975893">
   <label for="checkbox-group-1500575975893" class="fb-checkbox-group-label">Checkbox Group</label>
   <div class="checkbox-group">
      <div class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-group-1500575975893-0"><input name="checkbox-group-1500575975893[]" value="option-1" type="checkbox">Option 1</label></div>
      <div class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-group-1500575975893-1"><input name="checkbox-group-1500575975893[]" value="option-2" type="checkbox">option2</label></div>
      <div class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-group-1500575975893-2"><input name="checkbox-group-1500575975893[]" value="option-3" type="checkbox">option-3</label></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is part of my stylesheet.

```
.invalid checkbox-group:required:invalid {
    border: 3px solid #900;
}
```

My code does not produce anything. I cannot add any extra classes or IDs when I adjust the CSS, I can only use the classes or IDs I have.  The .invalid comes from a typescript file. The type script file is suppose to show all the invalid elements after the user presses submit.

Was I close or am I wayyy off. Any advice for on how to change the css so I could get the bordered box to show up correctly?

Here are some of my sources: [Delay HTML5 :invalid pseudo-class until the first event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920742/delay-html5-invalid-pseudo-class-until-the-first-event/32290765#32290765) ,
[Applying border to a checkbox in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697455/applying-border-to-a-checkbox-in-chrome) ,

Comment: Are "required" & "invalid" classes that are added by your type script file? Are they added to <div class="checkbox"> or to the input tag?

Comment: They are added to my Typescript file. They aren't added to the <div class="checkbox"> or the input tag.

Answer (score -1):

Use [jQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/jQuery).

There are three steps to this method:

1. wrap the inputs in a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element
2. add [required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) to all inputs
3. use jQuery to remove the attribute from all inputs once at least one input is checked

### Why this works

Empty `required` inputs inside the `form` make it [invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid)

You can then target the [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) form in CSS to create the border if no inputs are checked.

Working example:

```js
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
  !checkboxes.attr("required", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

```css
#myform {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent
}

#myform:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <label>Checkbox Group</label>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1" required> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2" required> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3" required> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4" required> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5" required> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
  </div>
</form>
```